# Getting envisage services in a Handler

Tags: python, plugins, enthought

I'm using envisage workbance and I want to get the service in the Handler.
In the `_tcp_send_changed` function how can I get the services. In the plugin there is the `self.application.get_service(....)` but here how can I reach them?

---

**UPDATED**

This is my view

```
class MCLidarGUIView( HasTraits ):         
    traits_ui_view = View( 
        VGroup( 
            HGroup( 
                Item( 'lidar_list',
                    show_label = False,
                    editor = TabularEditor( 
                        show_titles = False,
                        selected = 'selected',
                        editable = False,
                        multi_select = True,
                        adapter = LidarAdapter()                    
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            Item( 
                 "lidars_command"
            ),
            HGroup( 
                   Item( 'handler.tcp_send',
                        show_label = False,
                        editor = ButtonEditor( label = "TCP:Send" )                        
                ),
            )
        ),

        id = 'forwind.lidarapi.giuview',
        resizable = True,
        handler = MCLidarActions()

    )    

    lidar_list = [LidarObject( lidar_name = "No Connected Lidar" )]
    lidars_command = ''
```

and this is my handler:

```
class MCLidarActions( Handler ):

    tcp_send = Event 

    def object__updated_changed( self, info ):
        print info;
        pass;   

    def _tcp_send_changed( self ):
        print( " info" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class MyHandler(Handler):

```
def __init__(self, application, **traits):
     Handler.__init__(self, **traits)
     self.application = application
```

...

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing but from the [documentation](http://github.enthought.com/envisage/envisage_core_documentation/services.html) it seams like you have to register a service first. Maybe show us a bit more code so we can help better.

Comment: Yes that is true, there is the documentation, but you can get access to the application only if the class inherited from the Plugin class.

Comment: Isn't the handler part of you application?

Comment: Yes, it's part of my application, but a different class.

Comment: So why don't you pass the instance to the child class?

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner can you provide an example